# Wordpress,PhP,Javascrip не знаю в чем проблема,но специалисты данной категории поймут проблему

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

Всем привет нужна помощь,данные файла хранятся на сервере,подскажите ключевое слово.для поиска  нужного файла что-бы изменить название месяца,сайт был создан с помощью wordpress,и если не ошибаюсь файл должен быть в формате PhP или Javascript,как видно по скрину ниже картинки есть запись дата и снизу месяц на Турецком,хочу изменить название даты в корневой папки или файле,подскажите что можно сделать и как правильно решить данную проблему

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: исправлю себя,нужно изменить название месяца с Турецкого на другой язык

Comment: Почему вы уверены, что даты хранятся не в базе данных, а прямо в коде?

Comment: я не уверен,в этом вся проблема,пытался найти нужны файл через total Commander увы нету результат,подскажите как могу исправить данную проблему?